# Convert EPL image to PDF?

Tags: ups, image-formats, epl

I am using the UPS API to generate EPL labels to print on our thermal printer, which is working perfectly using CUPS and `lpr`.

However, I would like to be able to save that label in a computer-renderable format: GIF, PDF, PostScript - anything, really.

I have not been able to find a library to convert between raw EPL data to any other format. Is there a library that can do this? Or an LPR option or package which will output to a file, rather than a printer? How can I accomplish converting Eltron Programming Language files to something else?

Comment: I am currently implementing the other direction: from SVG to EPL. One could take my approach and inverse it. Please see: https://github.com/dittodhole/dotnet-System.Svg.Render.EPL

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to programmatically render EPL as an image. Yet.

Comment: EPL is a mostly text-based format; why wouldn't it be renderable?

Comment: Because you'd need to render the text to an image. There is no rendering engine for EPL.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? He's not lying, its 2017 and I cant find a library out there to render EPL2.

Comment: @andyknas `you'd need to render the text to an image` is not a valid reason, in SVG you also do so. It's just a `No one did it yet`